# Xamarin Forms PCL method call in closed app

Tags: android, xamarin, service, xamarin.forms

I developed a Xamarin Forms App in which I would like to call a method in the PCL part from my native android code. Specifically it's about the onTokenRefresh method of FCM, which runs as a service in the background. 
I want to upload the new token when the event is triggered. But I would like to have the code in the shared project instead of the native projects.

So this works as long as the app is running but when closed, the pcl code is crashing since it's not initialized.

Is it possible to run pcl code while the app is closed? Or is it possible to integrate some part of it into the background service?

Any help or idea is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this with that particular service since you are not starting it yourself (I believe). See this discussion to see if it might work in your scenario: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93030/is-it-possible-to-use-an-android-service-in-a-pcl

Comment: `...possible to run pcl code...` Yes, *but* that code has to be independent of any Forms code as you would not have an initialized Forms' application. So if you PCL/NetStd code is truly standalone code that you can instance and call methods without the "help" of a Forms' application, it will work fine when the OS instances your Service and calls the refresh method.

Answer (score 0):

You have create all static methods and have to call them from different platform
For E.g

```
  //In your native service android
     public async override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        try
        {

          var newToken= await Common.LogHelper.ServerLogHelper.LogMessage("Different paramter you pass");

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Common.LogHelper.ServerLogHelper.LogException(ex);
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }
    }

    //And in common class of PCL

    public static async string LogMessage()
    {
    var httpClientObject = new HttpClient();
                httpClientObject.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.TradesTekServiceURL);
                httpClientObject.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.TradesTekServiceURL);
                httpClientObject.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);

                string request = @"Your request string";

                HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appErrorLogMessage), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClientObject.PostAsync(request, httpContent);

                //Get data from reponse

                return NewToken;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers and comments.

I checked my upload code for the use of Xamarin forms and deleted were possible. Then I called it from native android and suddenly it works.